# MCE Remote Control - lirc Reponds - Now What?

Tags: vlc, lirc

My Hauppauge MCE remote now works with Ubuntu 13.10.   However, when I try to use something like VLC Media Player, nothing happens (e.g. the video does not pause when I press the pause button).

I have verified that the correct command is being echoed when I press the corresponding button.  (except ChanUp and ChanDown seem to be reversed, but not a problem).

Any ideas what my next steps are in dumping Windows forever?

```
/home/buck> $ irw
000000037ff05bef 00 VolUp mceusb_hauppauge
000000037ff05bef 01 VolUp mceusb_hauppauge
000000037ff05bec 00 ChanUp mceusb_hauppauge
000000037ff05bec 01 ChanUp mceusb_hauppauge
000000037ff05be7 00 Pause mceusb_hauppauge
000000037ff05be7 01 Pause mceusb_hauppauge
000000037ff05be9 00 Play mceusb_hauppauge
000000037ff05be9 01 Play mceusb_hauppauge
000000037ff05be7 00 Pause mceusb_hauppauge
000000037ff05be7 01 Pause mceusb_hauppauge
000000037ff05be7 00 Pause mceusb_hauppauge
000000037ff05be7 01 Pause mceusb_hauppauge
000000037ff05be7 00 Pause mceusb_hauppauge
000000037ff05be7 01 Pause mceusb_hauppauge
000000037ff05be7 00 Pause mceusb_hauppauge
000000037ff05be7 01 Pause mceusb_hauppauge
000000037ff05be7 00 Pause mceusb_hauppauge
000000037ff05be7 01 Pause mceusb_hauppauge
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working by doing two things that I found elsewhere on this site:

- I added a file called ~/.lircrc with the contents shown below.
- Then I went into VLC's advanced settings/interface and selected Infrared Remote Control Interface.  Under the "infrared" entry, I pointed to the ~/.lircrc

[image: Setup]

```
begin
 prog = vlc
 button = play
 config = key-play-pause
end
begin
 prog = vlc
 button = pause
 config = key-play-pause
end
begin
 prog = vlc
 button = stop
 config = key-stop
end
begin
 prog = vlc
 button = skip
 config = key-jump+medium
end
begin
 prog = vlc
 button = replay
 config = key-jump-short
end
begin
 prog = vlc
 button = forward
 config = key-next
end
begin
 prog = vlc
 button = rewind
 config = key-prev
end
begin
 prog = vlc
 button = up
 config = key-nav-up
end
begin
 prog = vlc
 button = down
 config = key-nav-down
end
begin
 prog = vlc
 button = left
 config = key-lav-left
end
begin
 prog = vlc
 button = right
 config = key-right
end
begin
 prog = vlc
 button = volup
 config = key-vol-up
 repeat = 1
end
begin
 prog = vlc
 button = voldown
 config = key-vol-down
 repeat = 1
end
begin
 prog = vlc
 button = mute
 config = key-vol-mute
end
begin
 prog = vlc
 button = pictures
 config = key-audiodelay-up
end
begin
 prog = vlc
 button = music
 config = key-audiodelay-down
end
begin
 prog = vlc
 button = more
 config = key-crop
end
```